# How to log initialisation script?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I have a certain script that i run to set up services on the machine. When i run script from command line, all services are started, but when it is run during initialisation, some of them fail to do so.

I would like to determine the reason for that. To that effect, i want to log execution of the script somewhere for later inspection. How do i do that?

My system is fedora, and i have put the script into rc.local (/etc/rc.d/rc.local).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your script into another one like the next code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/your_actual_script.sh 2>&1 >/var/log/script_exec.log
```